# javascript, changing image with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a page where in the center of the screen there is a div, and below there are a few  links. Each link, when clicked, must show in the div a different image. When a link is clicked, the current image must move to the left of the screen and fade out, at the same time the new image must appear from the right with fading and place itself in the div. What I did until now is in the following script, called on each link with

```
OnClick=("changeImage('name')")



function changeImage(param){
var image = $("#div");
image.animate({"queue": true, opacity: 0.0, right: '650px'}, 1200);
image.attr('src', 'img/'+param+'.png');
}
```

At the moment the images changes **before** moving to the left. Then it disappears.
I'd like the first image to move, fade out and then the second to appear from right.
Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#div").click(function(){
    var image = $(this);
    var param = 'example';
    image.animate({opacity: 0.0, right: '1000px'}, 1200).delay(100).animate({opacity: 1, right: '200px'}, 1200);
    setTimeout(function(){ image.attr('src', 'img/'+param+'.png').css('right','-1000px'); },1200);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nKpqU/

jQuery's effects `queue` only applies to just that: effects and animations. I also changed your `onclick` setup to bind the `click` event with jQuery's `.click`.

Comment: Hi, it is ok but the second image doesn't appear from right, it appears from left. How can I make it appear from right?

Comment: @maurice77 I updated my code. Note that `overflow-x: hidden` should be applied to the container of the image to prevent the horizontal scrollbar. However, it is commented out in the fiddle.